# Share global variables between Python scripts

Tags: python

I have 3 scripts: `params.py` (it defines a configuration class), `foo.py` (it uses that configuration) and `main.py` (it initializes the configuration and calls `foo`).

`params.py`:

```
class Config:
   def __init__(self, x=0):
      self.val = x

global config
config = Config()
```

`foo.py`:

```
from params import config

def foo():
   return config.val + 5
```

`main.py`:

```
from params import config
from foo import foo

config = Config(10)
print(foo())
```

But instead of print 15, it prints 5. How can I fix it? It occurs because when `foo.py` does the import, it initializes `config` with 0. But, what can I do to modify from `main` the `config` value and read the new value from all other scripts?

Thank you!

Comment: You experience here a good reason why most people refrain from using global variables: they are a pain, avoid them at all cost. If you do choose to use them, make sure you read all documentation about variable scope etc...

Comment: First, `global` doesn't do anything in a global scope. Second, Python doesn't have a process-wide namespace (aside from the built-in namespace), only per-module global namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you need to separate an object like `Config()` from the variables that may be referencing it at any given time. When `params.py` does `config = Config()`, it creates a `Config` object and assigns it to a variable in the `params` module namespace. It is `params.config`.

When `main.py` does `from params import config`, it adds a reference to this `Config` object to its own namespace. Now there are two references to the same object, one in `params.config` and another in `main.config`. So far, so good. `from X import Y` adds a binding to X.Y into the current namespace. Since `params.config` is a mutable class instance, `main` could change the values in that single `Config` object and it would be seen by all other referrers to that same object. `config.val = 10` would be seen by all.

Now things go off the rails. When `main` does `config = Config(10)`, it creates a new `Config` object and reassigns that variable to the `main` namespace. Now `params.config` references the first object and `main` references the second. That means changes made to the second object are not seen by the first.

If you want everyone to see the same object, you need to keep the namespace qualification. The scripts would change to

foo.py:

```
import params

def foo():
   return params.config.val + 5
```

main.py:

```
import params
from foo import foo

params.config = Config(10)
print(foo())
```

Now, all of the scripts are using the one variable `params.config` and see any changes made to that object. This is kindof fragile as you've seen. If anybody does `from params import config`, reassiging `params.config` doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds a good explanation. Thanks! But thus, is there no way to avoid using `params.config` instead of simply `config`?

Comment: As I mentioned, main could update attributes on the existing object, so all referrers would see it regardless of whether they've assigned it to a different variable. You could add functions to update en mass if this is a large configuration. I think this would be a more common approach.

Answer (score 1):

`global` only marks a name in a *local* scope as being global; it has no affect in a global scope, in that it is *already* global.

What you want isn't really possible, as global namespaces are specific to an individual module, not the process as a whole.

If the value is defined in `params.py`, you will need to access it via `params` from all other modules, include the `__main__` module created by your script.

`params.py`:

```
class Config:
   def __init__(self, x=0):
      self.val = x

config = Config()
```

`foo.py`:

```
import params

def foo():
   return params.config.val + 5
```

`main.py`:

```
import params
from foo import foo

params.config = params.Config(10)
print(foo())
```

---

If you simply *modified* the existing configuration, you could use

`params.py` (same as above):

```
class Config:
   def __init__(self, x=0):
      self.val = x

config = Config()
```

`foo.py` (same as your original `foo.py`):

```
from params import config

def foo():
   return config.val + 5
```

`main.py`

```
from params import config
from foo import foo

config.val = 10
print(foo())
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, I don't think this is a good idea, as you're essentially creating a global state that can change from any file that imports the configuration file. This is known as [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)).

**The best answer is to avoid this pattern altogether.** For example, come up with a way to use the configuration file in a read-only manner.

That being said, if you *really* want to do this, make the variable class-level rather than instance-level, so that there exists only one `val` shared across the entire program.

```py
class Config:
   val = 0
   def __init__(self, x=0):
      Config.val = x

global config
config = Config()
```

Then, running `main.py` will print `15`.

Comment: That has its own problems if you really do need multiple instances of `Config`.

Comment: That's why the best answer is to not make a shared global state. :)

Comment: This is still global state; even worse, you are now sharing a value across multiple instances of `Config` as well as sharing an instance of `Config` across multiple modules.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I stated right above that that the best approach is to avoid this pattern altogether.

Answer (score -1):

```
#params.py:

config = []


#main.py:

from params import config

def mess_with_config():
    #global config         - this is
    #config= [['stuff']]   - wrong!
    
    config.append(['stuff'])  # ✔
   
mess_with_config()
print(config)
```

You can import the instance of config from another file. Using global followed by assignment will cause the variable to be overwritten locally, in which case it will no longer point to the same object you imported. This is why you should use the class methods instead.